# Error while using Location prop in Gatsby Helmet

Tags: reactjs, location, gatsby, react-props, react-helmet

I'd like to add a class to the body tag containing the pathname.
I think I should have access to the location prop and that I should be able to pass this.
However location is being passed as null.

I'm using this as a resource : https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/location-data-from-props/

```
/**
 * SEO component that queries for data with
 *  Gatsby's useStaticQuery React hook
 *
 * See: https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/use-static-query/
 */

import React from "react"
import PropTypes from "prop-types"
import Helmet from "react-helmet"
import { useStaticQuery, graphql } from "gatsby"

const SEO = ({ description, lang, meta, title, location }) => {
  const mylocation = location.pathname;
  const { site } = useStaticQuery(
    graphql`
      query {
        site {
          siteMetadata {
            title
            description
          }
        }
      }
    `
  )

  const metaDescription = description || site.siteMetadata.description

  return (
    <Helmet
      htmlAttributes={{
        lang,
      }}
      title= "Hello"
      titleTemplate={'%s | ${site.siteMetadata.title}'}
      meta={[
        {
          name: 'description',
          content: metaDescription,
        },
        {
          property: 'og:title',
          content: mylocation,
        },
        {
          property: 'og:description',
          content: metaDescription,
        },
        {
          property: 'og:type',
          content: 'website',
        },
      ].concat(meta)}
    >
    <body className={mylocation} />
  </Helmet>
  )
}

SEO.defaultProps = {
  lang: 'en',
  meta: [],
  description: '',
}

SEO.propTypes = {
  description: PropTypes.string,
  lang: PropTypes.string,
  meta: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.object),
  title: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  location: PropTypes.string,
}

export default SEO
```

When rendering this page ->  http://localhost:8000/about/
I expect to see mylocation = /about

Instead I see

```
Error in function SEO in ./src/components/seo.js:14
Cannot read property 'pathname' of undefined

./src/components/seo.js:14
```

Why is my location prop undefined?

Is there a better way to add a unique class or ID to each page?

Comment: Are you passing history object from parent ? or are you navigating through `<Link/>` ?
If you're using `<Link/>`,then I believe you've configure `BrowserRouter` to navigate to the SEO component ? Please clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`location` is a top-level property so it's only available in page components, as you can see in the [docs](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/location-data-from-props/):

> the `location` prop is passed to any page component and represents
> where the app is currently, where you’d like it to go, and other
> helpful information.

So, to use it in the SEO component you will need to lift it down from any page component such as:

```
const AboutMePage = ({ location, otherProps }) => {

    return <Layout>
      <SEO location={location} 
           description={`Some description`}
           lang={`Some lang`}
           meta={`Some meta`}
           title={`Some title`} />
       ...
    </Layout>

}
```

And so on for the rest of the pages.

If you want to avoid code-breakings you can use a default value in case you miss passing the `props` down like:

```
const SEO = ({ description, lang, meta, title, location="some default value" }) => {}
```